# Is there any option to return the value after '-' using LPAD or LEFT or RIGHT?

Tags: formula, formula-field, validation-rule

Is there is any option to return the value after '-'in a field.Suppose I have a field A in which the value is abc-technicalrecuiter but the position of '-' is different everytime. I want this field to return only technical recruiter in reports. Is it possible using LPAD,RIGHT OR LEFT fUNCTIONS ??

Kindly help!!

Answer (score 3):

FORMULA Field for this could be like -

**I dont know How much I am going correct - Try this out and let me know - if I am missing something -**

**Eg:** 
Your_Field__c = abc-Team

LEN (Your_Field__c) = 8

FIND("-", Your_Field__c) = 3

**RIGHT(Your_Field__c, (LEN(Your_Field__c) - FIND("-", Your_Field__c)-1))**

= RIGHT(abc-Team, ((8-3)-1))
= RIGHT(abc-Team, 4)
= Team

Final Formula will be :

> RIGHT(Your_Field__c, (LEN(Your_Field__c) - FIND("-", Your_Field__c)-1))

00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

### Previous Answer (Using Apex Code)

Try this one with your Apex code

```
String s1 = 'abc-technicalRecruiter';
String s2 =  s1.substringAfter('-');

System.assertEquals('technicalRecruiter', s2);
```

//here you verify that s2 contains your Job name only ( whatever comes after "-" symbol)

For More help checkout following String Methods in given Link

- subString(index)
- subString(startindex,endindex)
- substringAfter(separator)
- substringAfterLast(separator)
- substringBefore(separator)
- substringBeforeLast(separator)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm

Comment: Hi Nilesh,Thanks for your help but is it possible using formulaes,I don't want to use the code since I am the admin

Comment: You mean you want to do it using "Formula Fields" ?

Comment: Updated Answer, Check it out, let me know

Comment: Look at `MID()` formula function for an alternative solution. MID does substring

Comment: Hi Nilesh,You are absolutely correct.Bang on the target!!Thanks man